# Unable to remove unwanted App Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, app, tenant

Inside our online sharepoint tenant, i want to remove unwanted App Permission which were created during the development of some SharePoint add-ins, so i went to Admin center >> Apps >> App Permission:-

[image]

then i search for some apps using the app identifier >> click on delete, as follow:-

[image]

but after confirming the delete , i can still see/search the app permission identifier.. any advice how i can permanently delete unwanted App Permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to uninstalling the app through pnp-powershell?

here is the command that you can try..

Uninstall-PnPApp -Identity 99a00f6e-fb81-4dc7-8eac-e09c6f9132fe -Scope tenant

Remove-PnPApp -Identity 99a00f6e-fb81-4dc7-8eac-e09c6f9132fe -Scope tenant

Replace identity with your app identity.

if you find it helpful please upvote.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. so what is the app is registered inside a site collection ? should i remove it from the site collection first?

Comment: You can directly remove it for tenant level. if it is giving error then user -Force command. I you find it help full please mark as answer and  upvote it.

Comment: but in this case we will have an orphan app permission inside the site. is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

**Please run the below pnp PowerShell command as an administrator:**

```
#Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://crescentintranet.sharepoint.com/sites/projects"
  
#Connect to SharePoint Online App Catalog site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin
 
#Uninstall the specified app from the current site
Uninstall-PnPApp -Identity 99a00f6e-fb81-4dc7-8eac-e09c6f9132fe

#Remove the specified app from the tenant scoped app catalog
Remove-PnPApp -Identity 99a00f6e-fb81-4dc7-8eac-e09c6f9132fe
```

More information, please refer to :

- [Uninstall-PnPApp](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/uninstall-pnpapp?view=sharepoint-ps)
- [Remove-PnPApp](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/remove-pnpapp?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: thanks for the reply.. so you mean i need first to remove the app from the related site collection? now for some apps i do not know their site collection.. so is there a way to know the site collection for each app?

Comment: You can run directly “Remove-PnPApp -Identity 99a00f6e-fb81-4dc7-8eac-e09c6f9132fe”. You can remove the specified app from the tenant scoped app catalog. Have a nice day!

Comment: but in this case we will have an orphan app permission inside the site. is this correct?

Comment: I think we should not have an orphan app as we are manually uninstalling it and  removing it. did you check is it present as orphan app in side site?